# CSS, JS, jQuery slide down list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'd need some help with pure CSS, JS and jQuery slide down list that can be animated with jQuery or with the methods themselves. 3 hidden lists would be visible showing "CSS" "JavaScript" and "jQuery". On click a list would move down with all the content, showing part of the code that works as the slide down list function. Only one list can be active or shown at a time. I have no idea how to manage to do pure CSS or JavaScript slide down menu, jQuery won't be a problem. Also I can't seem to manage to get all of the content below active list to slide down also, instead of hovering over the text and covering it. I'd be greatful for some help.

Comment: Can you post your html code ?

Comment: What have you tried that did not work? Also, would be nice to see a jsFiddle demo